# How to add data from a form in offline mode and when user back online this data is passed to database with Service Workers

Tags: angular, ionic2, indexeddb, service-worker, offline-mode

i want to give my app user a privilege that if he/she enters a form in an **offline** mode it is to be saved on **IndexedDB** (or any alternative) and when he/she regain network access these data is to saved to a database.How can this be done with **Ionic2/Angular2** with the help of **ServiceWorker**?

Comment: Carefully (: Lot of moving parts to make this work, and there's no easy solution, I'm afraid. I suggest you do some research online; I can recommend [Offline Web Applications](https://www.udacity.com/course/offline-web-applications--ud899) course as a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.i had already watched the course.even though it covers almost all about offline first approach i cannot get anything about clientside storing and synching from https://www.udacity.com/course/offline-web-applications

Comment: This is a service worker capability called "background sync", here's a nice intro article to it https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/12/background-sync

Comment: Thank u  @ArnelleBalane

Comment: @neerajnarayanan you're welcome, good luck! :)

Comment: can i add image from my localmachine to indexeddb when user is completely offline.i added data from a form already to indexedDB;now i have to add images too.please answer.